# Why end tags used on void elements don't break the HTML?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and I'm not understanding what is "ilegal" to do,  if I code the following in C++ I will have a redefinition error.

```
int a = 2;
int a = 3;
```

But for example, in HTML Standard I found: " Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements." ([source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements)) So I would expect that the following HTML would kinda break:

```
<html>
<p>hello, insert a name <input> </input> </p>
</html>
```

But it works just fine, So what is illegal, that you "break" html?

Comment: Because browsers make a very good effort at fixing your mistakes and rendering a complete page regardless of markup errors. That's why you can very well write `<h1>Hello!` into an `.html` document and the browser will happily parse it and display it as a heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run that through https://validator.w3.org/, it will tell you "Error: Stray end tag `input`." So it really is invalid. Browsers are just really, really lenient of invalid HTML and will always try to keep going and guess what you may have meant.

Comment: Wow, thats great! I was in doubt about other things just like using the `<p>` element and the doctype, and the validator tell them all. Is there a way to make browsers don't be that lenient?

Comment: @Roman That's what XHTML was meant to do, but it was kind of a flop.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<frong>HTML</frong> is <fnord/> very forgiving <sasquatch/>. Browsers will try to render what they can, even if the input is technically invalid. </input></output></updoot></frobozz>
```